# Disable Two-Factor Authentication in ASP.NET Identity 2.0.0-beta1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I'm using the latest 2.0.0-beta1 release of ASP.NET Identity and I don't want to utilise the new two-factor authentication support.  In fact I want to remove the additional database columns EmailConfirmed, PhoneNumber, PhoneNumberConfirmed and TwoFactorEnabled but I can't see where I need to override the Identity classes to disable this functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement your own UserStore to remove the functionality.  The generic constraint on Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore is that the TUser is of type IdentityUser so you can't remove this while using the default EF implementation.

So you would implement your own IUserStore and not implement IUserTwoFactorStore or IUserPhoneNumberStore and then you also fully control what your tables look like.

Comment: While it's true that one has to implement own CustomUserStore consuming IUserStore, the CustomUserStore also requires inheriting IUserTwoFactorStore too, simply because SignInManager blindly checks for GetTwoFactorEnabledAsync method. Still, constructing a custom UserStore is the necessary step here.

Comment: Yeah that's a bug in SignInManager

Comment: @FeritBuyukkececi's comment is exactly the bit that I was missing.  You should add it to your solution.