# is it possible to disable two factor authentication in asp.net Identity?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, two-factor-authentication

I'm developing an app in asp.net mvc with identity, i just found out that it is prepared to be configured with two factor authentication. 
 What if i don't want to use it? How can i disable two factor authentication in asp.net identity?
 
Can i simply remove all the methods that use it in my solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable Two-Factor Authentication in ASP.NET Identity 2.0.0-beta1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21860648/disable-two-factor-authentication-in-asp-net-identity-2-0-0-beta1)

Answer (score 1):

Since i wasn't intrested in removing fields of 2factauth from database, I simply removed all the methods that wasn't useful in ManageController.
Then i coded a new View that allow to manage personal info and change password.